# Creating Installer Of Several Apps

Tags: c#, c++, installation, windows-installer

I have some applications, some of them were written in MFC and some of them were written in .NET.

I want to create a single installer that will install all those applications on a "Clean" machine (without any development environment on it). The installer, besides the applications, 
needs to install the appropriate .NET framework and the VC runtime environment.

Other things:

1. I don't have access to the code of all those applications.
2. The apps will be installed only on windows machines.
3. None of the applications is web based (Win applications).

Does any one know some good installation tool that will help me with this task?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page):

> NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) is a professional open source system to create Windows installers. It is designed to be as small and flexible as possible and is therefore very suitable for internet distribution.
>   Being a user's first experience with your product, a stable and reliable installer is an important component of succesful software. With NSIS you can create such installers that are capable of doing everything that is needed to setup your software.
>   NSIS is script-based and allows you to create the logic to handle even the most complex installation tasks. Many plug-ins and scripts are already available: you can create web installers, communicate with Windows and other software components, install or update shared components and more.

And [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/):

> The WiX toolset builds Windows installation packages from XML source code. The toolset integrates seamlessly into build processes.

WIX is more complex and powerful.

Comment: WIX has the advantage of creating MSI installers, which integrate seemlessly with Microsoft technologies for automatically distributing software within company networks. NSIS installers are proprierary.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to gor's answer I'd like to add [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) as a very powerful and scriptable installer environment.

Also, like NSIS, it creates proprietary installer applications instead of MSI installers.